# How to add margin in materialize css?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, materialize

Ive been reading the documents and trying to find out if other people had the same questions. But i werent able to find any. Is there any way I can add space between the buttons? Right now they are right next to each other. Thanks!

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Todo extends React.Component {

    state = {
        color:null
    }

    render() {

        let color;
        if(this.props.todo.priorityLevel === "3" ) {
             color = "#ff5252 red accent-2";
        } else if(this.props.todo.priorityLevel === "2") {
            color =  "#ff8a65 deep-orange lighten-2";
        } else {
            color = "#fff176 yellow lighten-2";
        }

        return(
            <div className={"card-panel " + color}>
                <div id="todoInfo">
                    <h2>{`Title: ${this.props.todo.todoTitle}`}</h2>
                    <span id="todoDescription">{`Description: ${this.props.todo.description}`}</span>
                    <span id="todoPriorityLevel">{`Priority Level: ${this.props.todo.priorityLevel}`}</span>
                </div>
                <div id="todoActions">
                    <button className="btn-floating btn-large cyan pulse actionButtons" onClick={()=>this.props.dispatch({type:"EDIT_TODO", id: this.props.todo.id})}>Edit</button>
                    <button className="btn waves-effect #d50000 red accent-4 pulse actionButtons" onClick={()=>this.props.dispatch({type:"DELETE_TODO", id: this.props.todo.id})}>Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default connect()(Todo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `style={{ marginRight: '40px !important' }}` on the first button.

Alternatively, you might get a default gap if you use `<a>` tags instead of `<button>`

Comment: I am aware of this method. Just was wondering if I can do this with materialize to keep the code consistent. But Thank you!